# Question about Mexican vs Chinese passport strength

Tags: visa-free-entry, visas-on-arrival, chinese-citizens, e-visas, mexican-citizens

Why is the Mexican passport much stronger than the Chinese passport, despite both countries having relatively similar standards of living and GDP per capita?

Comment: This question is probably better answered on the [Politics.SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com) as it is not really about travel

Comment: In many cases per capita values are more meaningful... This is one of the cases where the absolute amount (population) may matter more

Comment: The fact that Mexico has a large tourism industry is surely part of the answer.  They therefore have a permissive visa regime, so other countries are likely to be permissive toward Mexican citizens.  Also China's communist government is probably a contributing factor.  Definitely a better question for [Politics.SE] than here.

Comment: I remember getting into China being expensive and a pain in the arse (while Taiwan, South Korea and Japan were no problem whatsoever). So countries are much more likely to let people from Taiwan, South Korea and Japan enter.

Answer (score 3):

Passport rankings are based on freedom of movement and visa-free travel open to holders of particular passports. This has nothing to do with GDP or wealth, but how easy is for citizens of such a country to travel without visa.

Comment: Sorry for the DV but IMO this does not answer the question at all. The question does not ask for the definition of passport strength, but for the reasons for the large difference between two countries' passports' strengths.

Comment: feci quod potui, faciant meliora potentes

Comment: There is actually a link between the two: countries are more likely to grant visa-free entry to citizens of "rich" countries, because they are less likely to try to immigrate. That's why the "strongest" passports are all from "rich" and stable countries and the "weakest" ones from countries which are "poor", unstable, at war, etc. It's not a 1:1 relationship though, as there are other factors at play, and this is probably what OP is inquiring about: why in this case, two countries with similar GDP/wealth are treated so differently by the others.

Answer (score 2):

This is purely about politics. The standards of living and GDP (per capita or absolute) are not the only considered criteria. While unable to provide an exhaustive answer, I can outline a few points:

1. There are many people willing to emigrate from both China and Mexico, but the Mexicans are generally not seen as a threat (outside of the US). Chinese people could be seen as possible spies. Of course, I'm nowhere near suggesting that a visa requirement can prevent espionage, but that's the way things are.
2. China is a global power, many countries want to have strong business relationships with it, but there are not many countries that really trust China as a friend. Perhaps certain African countries consider China a friend, and some of them do grant visa-free access to Chinese nationals. Despite numerous declarations of friendship, the level of trust between China and Russia is not high enough to enable mutual unconditional visa-free access.
3. A lot depends on how likely are citizens of a given country to get to a destination country protected by visa requirements. For example, the Schengen Area allows visa-free access to citizens of many Latin American countries (incl. Mexico), some of which are really poor and dangerous. At the same time, the Schengen Area requires visas from e.g. Turkish citizens. Why? Because illegal immigrants from Latin America are much less likely to get to the Schengen Area than illegal immigrants from Turkey. Similarly, Mexicans need a visa to enter the United States, but they don't need one to enter Canada. Apparently, those Mexicans who can afford a flight to Canada are considered "safe".

Finally, even though the PRC citizens need visas to many countries, I'd say they are quite likely to get one wherever they apply (except India). The same is true for most tourists willing to enter China.

Comment: *there are not many countries that are on friendly terms with China* citation needed for this: outside Western countries and specific countries in local conflicts with China (eg, South China Sea neighbours), China is generally seen quite positively.

Comment: @MJeffryes to be "seen positively" is not enough. Visa-free access needs (among other things) much more friendship and trust between respective governments, something that China doesn't have. In Russia, China is viewed overwhelmingly positively, but the visa requirements remain in place.

Comment: Yes, I'm still disputing this is the case. The Belt and Road initiative has 151 member countries, who can all presumably be categorised as being on friendly terms with China. Yet many of those countries don't permit visa free access to Chinese citizens. So 'friendliness' seems irrelevant to the answer.

Comment: @MJeffryes first of all, this a speculative answer to a speculative question, so it's about as exact as it gets. However, to get into more detail, I'd say many countries want to have a close relationship with China (for business purposes), but they don't actually trust it. That might explain the discrepancy between the high number of countries in the Belt and Road initiative, and the low number of countries that admit Chinese citizens without a visa.